# How to name a B+Tree key/value map collection that also acts as the container for other collections

Tags: c++, data-structures, collections, subtree, b-tree-index

I am looking for some advice, as I am currently drawing a blank on the naming for a collection abstraction. This may be a slightly off-topic question, so apologies if that is deemed the case.

I am working on a library that provides B+Tree storage, and supports several kinds of collection interfaces over this B+Tree, such as key/value maps and sorted sets.

A special kind of collection is one that explicitly supports nested child collections in addition to allowing regular map key/value storage. This provides the means for name space/table space/key space support.

My current working name for this collection abstraction is "MultiMap". But this does not feel right and is not really consistent with e.g. an STL multimap. But so far I have not been able to come up with anything better.

Any suggestions for a better name would be appreciated.

As extra info, refer to the interface definition I am considering now below:

```
/** Represents a map that can be the container for nested collections. 
 *  This allows having arbitrarily deep nesting for collections to support
 *  organization into (hierarchies of) separate name, key or table spaces. 
 *  So instead of for example having a map that contains variable length 
 *  keys such as "users/1", "users/2", etc. a nested collection "users" 
 *  could be created that has fixed size integer keys (1, 2, ...). Note 
 *  that storage for collections can be expensive. If not stored as a 
 *  small embedded collection with only a few items, it will take up at 
 *  least one physical storage page. Like in a regular map, all keys must 
 *  be unique and items are stored in sorted key order. */
class IMultiMapCursor : public virtual IMapCursor {
public:
    /** Positions the cursor at the first nested child collection, if any */
    virtual bool SeekFirstNestedCollection() = 0;

    /** Moves the cursor to the next nested child collection, if any */
    virtual bool SeekNextNestedCollection() = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a key/value map with the given @map_id under the
     *  map for this cursor, and returns a cursor to the nested map. */
    virtual IMapCursor* OpenNestedMap(
        const Slice& map_id, 
        const MapOptions& map_options = MapOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a key/value map with the given @path_to_map, 
     *  relative to the map for this cursor, and returns a cursor to the 
     *  nested map. */
    virtual IMapCursor* OpenNestedMap(
        const CollectionPath& path_to_map,
        const MapOptions& map_options = MapOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a key/value multi-map with the given @map_id under 
     *  the map for this cursor, and returns a cursor to the nested map. */
    virtual IMultiMapCursor* OpenNestedMultiMap(
        const Slice& map_id, 
        const MapOptions& map_options = MapOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a key/value multi-map with the given @path_to_map,
     *  relative to the map for this cursor, and returns a cursor to the
     *  nested map. */
    virtual IMultiMapCursor* OpenNestedMultiMap(
        const CollectionPath& path_to_map,
        const MapOptions& map_options = MapOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a sorted set with the given @set_id under the map
     *  for this cursor, and returns a cursor to the nested set. */
    virtual ISortedSetCursor* OpenNestedSortedSet(
        const Slice& set_id, 
        const SetOptions& set_options = SetOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a sorted set with the given @path_to_set,
     *  relative to the map for this cursor, and returns a cursor to the
     *  nested set. */
    virtual ISortedSetCursor* OpenNestedSortedSet(
        const CollectionPath& path_to_set,
        const SetOptions& set_options = SetOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a non-sorted set with the given @set_id under the 
     *  map for this cursor, and returns a cursor to the nested set. */
    virtual ISetCursor* OpenNestedSet(
        const Slice& set_id, 
        const SetOptions& set_options = SetOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a non-sorted set with the given @path_to_set, relative to the 
     *  map for this cursor, and returns a cursor to the nested set. */
    virtual ISetCursor* OpenNestedSet(
        const CollectionPath& path_to_set,
        const SetOptions& set_options = SetOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a list with the given @list_id under this map, and 
     *  returns a cursor to the nested list. */
    virtual IListCursor* OpenNestedList(
        const Slice& list_id, 
        const ListOptions& list_options = ListOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Opens or creates a list with the given @path_to_list under this map, 
     *  and returns a cursor to the nested list. */
    virtual IListCursor* OpenNestedList(
        const CollectionPath& path_to_list, 
        const ListOptions& list_options = ListOptions::kOpenExisting) = 0;

    /** Renames the existing collection with id @current_id to @new_id. 
     *  Requires (a) @new_id to be available. (b) the collection not to 
     *  have an open cursor. */
    virtual bool RenameNestedChildCollection(const Slice& current_id, const Slice& new_id) = 0;
};
```

Comment: CollectionMap? GenericMap? AnyMap? CollectionOrKeyValueMap?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the wording of your question, how about the obvious `NestedMap`?

Another one that comes to mind is `HyperMap`. As per definition, **hyper** means *beyond; above; exceeding; excessively; above normal*, all of which could be used to describe the fact that the map stores more than just the normal key/value pair.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Rado. It appears this is not a very popular question, given low views, a first single answer and my recently earned 'Tumbleweed' badge ;) despite a modest bounty for encouragement. 
I had considered `NestedMap`, but that word implies that the map is nested (i.e. a child itself), where it is the parent in which child collections are nested.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the nesting of spaces this collection allows, how about HierarchicalMap, HierarchyMap or HierMap?

Comment: I kinda like this name, however without intellisense support I suspect quite a few typing probems for non-native english developers, as "hierarchy" is not that easy a word.

Answer (score 1):

How about `TreeMap`?
A mapped value could be a single-node tree (a leaf), representing a key/value pair, or a non-single-node tree for anything else. Every value would perfectly satisfy the Tree definition, allowing consistent naming, provided that these structures are actually trees (i.e. no interconnects to siblings). Note that even a key without a value would be a valid tree.

Comment: I agree that would seem like a logical name, as this is how the underlying implementation solves this problem for some of these collection interfaces, albeit with optimized node layouts (e.g. a leaf node for a sorted set needs no storage room for values). However other collection types not structured as trees (non sorted lists and sets) can also be stored as children in this 'multimap'.

Comment: Well, unsorted lists and sets in an n-ary tree _are_ children, aren't they? Take a root and add all elements of the list/set as direct leaves. Part of the very nature of B+Trees is the fact that it allows efficient in-order traversion, making it quite suitable for lists and sets. After all, a B+Tree is also a Tree. I understand, though, that people using your class might not find it intuitive that you can store lists in something containing the word Tree.

Comment: Ah, now I see your interface description. So _that's_ where your problem lives in the abstraction hierarchy. I probably missed the point ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since it maps keys/values in a tree: KeyTree/MapTree, CollectionTree
Or since values can be considered discrete: DiscreteTree / DiscreteStructureTree

will update with more thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `SuperMap`!

Since it's a Map that can map other Maps/Collections, some names that come to mind are `CollectionMap`, `BucketMap`, maybe even `BucketTree` depending on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`FlexMap` as your collection abstraction features flexibility.

Or `AlexMap` or `ALXmap` as you invented this.